# Getting FB user's data from AWS "CognitoIdentityCredentials" using Facebook Login

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, aws-api-gateway

Good day,

I've got an API setup, it's sitting behind AWS's APIGateway, secured with IAM, in this case it's a Cognito Federated ID pool.

I have the following code:

```
function doFacebookLogin() {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        fbAuthToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

        doFetchProfile();
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email', return_scopes: true});
}

function doFetchProfile() {
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-1:*****************************',
        Logins: {
            'graph.facebook.com': fbAuthToken
        }
    });

    // Obtain AWS credentials
    AWS.config.credentials.get(function () {
        apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
            accessKey: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
            secretKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
            sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken,
            region: 'eu-west-1'
        });

        apigClient.userProfileGet({
            'x-fb-access-token': fbAuthToken
        }).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Right now, I'm sending the Facebook AccessToken in the header, because my server (sitting behind the AWS APIGateway) needs access to the user's facebook profile data.

I was hoping that by simply signing into the Cognito Federated ID pool, using the Facebook provider, would be enough to have AWS's APIGateway SDK pass the accessToken (in some form or another) along with every request.

It doesn't seem to be the case, I can't find a way to extract the Facebook data I need without sending the AccessToken in the header as per the example above.

Am I wrong in my understanding of what *should* happen?

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're server behind API Gateway needs the Facebook access token to access some Facebook APIs, then yes you'll always need to pass the Facebook access token through in API GW.

The Cognito federated login allows you to exchange a Facebook token for AWS credentials for accessing AWS-protected services.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for the response. I'm using Cognito Federated Login, as per the code in my question. (Unless I'm not, but I think I am?). I'm thus able to access IAM protected resources. 

My base question was "how would I access facebook credentials, without sending the facebook access token, just using cognito". AWS Cognito has since added a federated id mapping section which I'm exploring.